# Generic error handler for Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I am trying to put in place a generic error handler for my models and collection. I did something like this:

```
var originalFetchModel = Backbone.Model.prototype.fetch;
Backbone.Model.prototype.fetch = function(options){
    var originalError = options.error;
    options.error = function(model, error){
        if (originalError){ originalError(model, error, options); }
        //my logic here
    }
    originalFetchModel.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

This is working pretty fine for fetch but I cannot make it work for save.
When I do somethink like this:

```
model.save(modelDetails, {
              success: function (model) {
                  //logic
              }
          });
```

I am under the impression that the error callback is overriden.
Does someone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override [`Backbone.sync`](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) and use the promise returned by jQuery to globally handle errors. Something like

```
(function() {
    var orgsync = Backbone.sync;

    Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
        var xhr = orgsync.call(this, method, model, options);
        xhr.fail(function() {
            console.log('global error handler', method);
        });
        return xhr;
    }
})();
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/qm6z4sqy/